# PowerBI - DAX - Sum of a column based on criteria x

Tags: powerbi, dax

Im trying to sum something using calculate but can't really figure out how.

For example

```
  ID   Value   Source  
 ---- ------- -------- 
  A        1   Mo      
  B        2   Ba      
  A        1   Ba      
  C        3   Mo      
  B        2   Mo      
  D        4   Ba
```

What i'm trying to calculate is not to filter out either source but to take either one source. For example, if I have ID: A and both Source Mo & Ba, then pick either one for the sum and not both. Would this be possible using calculate? I thought of

```
Measure1 = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1),SWITCH(Table1[Source],"Mo",Table1[Value],"Ba",Table1[Value]))
```

(It didn't work)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you choose which one do you want?

Comment: It's either one, because it has the same value. Do you think i can apply a filter or something? Like Distinct?

Comment: If you need one value, use `min` or `max` instead of `sum`.

Comment: Ohhhh! True that!! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a simple filter like this:

```
Measure1 = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1), Table1[Source] = "Mo")
```

Another possibility would be to simply filter out one or the other at the report/page/visual level.